# NoReverseMatch at/ in base.html

Tags: python, django, blogs, django-errors

so when I run my code locally, it works fine. But when I run it online I get NoReverseMatch at/. I've gone through the code for the past 2 hours but still can't figure out the reason why.

P.S: If there is unnecessary code here do let me know so I can take it off, stackoverflow tells me there's too much code and no explanation here.

**base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ranindu's Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-header">
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
  {% endif %}
    <h1><a href="/">First Blog Success!</a></h1>
</div>
<div class="content container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .forms import PostForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts' : posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})

def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
else:
    form = PostForm()
return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form':form})

def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

[image: Error Screenshot in base.html line 13]

Comment: your views please..

Comment: Are you running the same version of Python (3.6.0) and Django (1.11.7) on your development environment?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 16.04. And on my terminal I have Python 2.7.12 and Python 3.5.2. My django version is 1.11.5. I git pull'd a couple of times before, and it worked fine online. After adding the security features to make adding and editing articles available for only the person logged into django admin, it stopped working. (https://github.com/Ranindu/my-first-blog.git)

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified you app name while mentioning the url.
Try using
{% url 'your_app_name:post_new' %}